# Changing the NLS_DATE_FORMAT in c#

Tags: c#, oracle, date

I am trying to change the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` of a query and I am struggling to do so.
I have used two approaches

1st

```
// Use the command to change the format
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = \'YYYY-MM-DD\'", conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

// Then do another command
OracleCommand mainCommand = new OracleCommand("SELECT * FROM dates_table", conn);
OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while(reader.Read())
{
    // Read Data
}
```

This option's queries both succeed, yet the date format still contains the time (HH:MM:SS)

2nd

```
// Put both commands in the same sql statement
string sql = "ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = \'YYYY-MM-DD\';";
sql += "SELECT * FROM dates_table";
OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(sql, conn);
OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while(reader.Read())
{
    // Read Data
}
```

This option does not succeed and gives me the error `ORA-0091` which seems to be the semicolon in the first statement. I have also tried removing the semicolon, yet it produces a `ORA-00922` error.

I am a bit stuck as of now, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you trying to format it using the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`? Just format the date time value in C# to the format that you want.

Comment: I concur; this is a display problem.  Do your display formatting client-side.

Comment: @MT0 The data is not being changed into a c# DateTime and cannot be. The queries I am dealing with are not always the same and I have no way of telling what is a date and what isn't. I was hoping that I could do a blanket change for every date being accessed

Comment: @RobertHarvey is there a reason not to do it during the query?

Comment: Yes, if you're not actually retrieving DateTime objects.   Presumably then, you're simply retrieving TEXT from the database?  Your remark about not being able to tell what is a date and what isn't is very worrying; normally, databases have a stable schema that you can rely on.

Comment: You should also read https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Setting `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` will **not have any effect** on the date display format in your client - provided you write your code properly. (which I cannot verify without any table structure and code of `// Read Data`)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I did not know this, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An oracle `DATE` is a binary data type and does **NOT** store a format so when you get the date column in a 3rd-party application (i.e. C#) you will only get the binary data representing years, months, days, hours, minutes and seconds and not any format.

The `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter is the internal format Oracle will use in the user's session to implicitly cast dates to (and from) strings.

The SQL/Plus and SQL Developer client applications also use the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter to control how the binary date values are displayed to the user but this formatting is done on the client application (and not by the Oracle database).

---

If you want to format a `DATE` data type then do the formatting in C#.

If you really want to format it in the database then use `TO_CHAR` to convert each date column (without a format) to a formatted string.

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(date_column, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS formatted_date_column
FROM   dates_table
```

Comment: I did not know that NLS_DATE_FORMAT had no effect on displayed values, thank you